# Flutter Firestore Timestamp.now() giving the wrong value

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I building a chat app, with Cloud Firestore as the backend. The code for message update:

```
  void _submitMessage() async {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    print(DateTime.now());
    User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final userData = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chat').add(
      {
        'message': _newMessage,
        'user': user.uid,
        'createdAt': DateTime.now(),
        'username': userData.data()['username']
      },
    );
    _controller.clear();
  }
```

The latest message sent is on today March 19th, 5:37PM Central US Time. The chat value is,

[image]

Is there a reason for this bug? The cloud_firestore version is 1.0.1.

EDIT: I have tested this with `Timestamp.now()` as well. The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a with my device's date. Fixing the device date fixed the problem.

EDIT: In situations where you want client independent time stamp, you should use `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`, instead of Timestamp.now().

Answer (score 1):

Use Timestamp.now(). That should work.

Comment: I have used Timestamp.now() as well. Sorry I did not mention it. Timestamp.now is also giving me the same issue. I have mentioned that is the edit.

Comment: What does print(DateTime.Now().toString()) return? Same as what is being stored in firebase?

Comment: It seems my emulator device has the wrong date. But isn't Timestamp.now() supposed to get the server timestamp?

the last message was at around 6:05 Central time, and I got this `Timestamp(seconds=1615415474, nanoseconds=732404000)`

Comment: You're using DateTime.Now() locally, and generating the data while still in the emulator and then sending it to firebase, which will store it as how it got it. Did this solve your error?

Comment: Well I switched to Timestamp.now(). I fixed the time on my emulator, and the timestamp for correct on the Firestore field. However, as soon as changed the time on my emulator again, I got the same issue. But I guess this is not a flutter issue. I will close this can create a new question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Awesome, you're most welcome! If this helped solved your problem, kindly mark it as an answer, thanks!